# Python script that turns bluetooth on and off

Tags: scripts, bluetooth

I want to try out a python script that turns bluetooth on and off. I have no idea where to start. Help please.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a Python script that you already have? Or are you asking how to write a Python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can run terminal commands in python.

The terminal lines are:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

and

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

To run them in python:

```
import os
os.system("rfkill block bluetooth")


import os
os.system("rfkill unblock bluetooth")
```

Or you could use:

```
subprocess.call(["rfkill", "block", "bluetooth"])

subprocess.call(["rfkill", "unblock", "bluetooth"])
```

Comment: OK, these are terminal commands, but how exactly they're supposed to be run from python ?

Comment: The shell part looks fine. In the Python part, the second `import` is superfluous and the argument of `os.system()` must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: We are in 2017. Please don't advice anyone to use os.system. It is from the Flinstones's age and deprecated. Then there are other things, but don't need to mention.

Comment: Hi! Please help with the answer. os.system can still be used to date. We also have subprocess that we can use. We're you referring to a different approach?

Comment: You can use both `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()`. The first one will wait for the command to finish, the latter will move on. `os.system()` is really old fashioned, outdated and deprecated. The fact that it still works does not mean you should.